# How do you programmatically create organized photo albums in iOS with xcode 6 using swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, structure, photo, photo-gallery

I don't know proper terminology but I either want to create an album with sub-albums, or would you say a Folder with sub-albums... 
I am writing an app that downloads photos from the web and it also downloads some additional information about each photo which I save in a SQLite database. These photos were specifically uploaded by different Game Cameras setup out in the woods at different locations.

On my app I need to keep all the photos organized by the camera that uploaded the photo. I also would prefer to allow the user to use the standard iOS Photos app to view photos and do whatever they would like with them. Lets say my app is called "CamWatch". So I think what I want to do is to create (I may not be using the correct terminology) custom albums with the following structure:

```
CamWatch
CamWatch/Rye Field Camera 
CamWatch/Cold Creek Camera 
CamWatch/Whatever Camera
```

I have watched the videos by Tony Abboud and from that I have been able to create the base album `CamWatch`. Because a user could have 25+ cameras I really want to organize all photos under a sub-album (Camera Description) which is under the parent CamWatch album.

I am currently using the latest xCode 6.2 with the Photos framework and writing everything in Swift (I don't know Obj-C).

Any examples how to create the sub-albums and then how to save a photo file to one of those sub-albums would be greatly appreciated.

As a bonus it would be nice to know how to access a photo back by its "camera description/folder" and the photos file name (not by asset index).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

if you create new album named CamWatch, you can't create sub album. so you should create new folder named Camwatch,then you can create sub album in CamWatch